# How to substitute exception?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I want to substitute an exception and it's fields.

Something like that:

```
var webExcetion = Substitute.For<WebException>();
webExcetion.Response.Returns(httpWebResponse);
substituteForHttp.GetResponse(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(x => { throw webExcetion; });
```

This code throws Castle.Proxies.ExceptionProxy or NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnException by NSubstitute.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WebException` class does not have virtual members, so NSubstitute can not do much with it (it works by creating an instance of a derived type using Castle DynamicProxy, then changes the instance to work as a substitute by overriding all the virtual members).

In this case it should be fine to work around this problem by using a real `WebException`:

```
WebException webException = 
    new WebException("test", null, webExceptionStatus, httpWebResponse);
```

This will set the `Response` property to `httpWebResponse` as required.

Hope this helps.